# Leibniz Rule with Inverse of CDF

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with PDF and CDF, $f$ and $F$, respectively. Now, we define $Z(w)=F^{-1}\left( \frac{p+g-w}{p+g} \right)$, and $\Lambda(Z(w))=\int_{0}^{Z(w)}(Z(w)-x)f(x)dx$ and $\Theta(Z(w))=\int_{Z(w)}^{\infty}(x-Z(w))f(x)dx$.

Based on these definitions, I define a function $\Pi(w)=(w-c)D+(w-c)\left[\Lambda(Z(w))-\Theta(Z(w))\right]$. I am wondering how to find the derivative of $\Pi(w)$ with respect to $w$. How is it possible to define the inverse of CDF? Is it possible to determine the result based on hazard rate?

Comment: If this is a question about _Mathematica_, have a look at [InverseCDF](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html?q=InverseCDF).

Comment: Actually I want to find the derivative of $\Pi(w)$ w.r.t. $w$